# Sample size and Quality Control

Tags: sampling, sample-size, quality-control

Why does quality control becomes difficult when the sample size is large?
[image]

Comment: In the context of that slide I'm guessing it's because the more samples you take, the more possible variation there is and so less quality control (defining quality control as lack of variation).

Answer (score 1):

As sample size grows, many other things grow with it.  Each sample takes time and equipment to collect.

As the number of samples grow, the number of people (who may add more variation to the process) grows as well.  This growth requires additional process to help manage the variation, additional gage studies, &c.

The equipment may experience increased tool wear or need to become automated to handle the sample size.  Both changes would also require additional calibration and certifications.

You can also look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203113/using-control-charts-with-very-large-subgroup-size) question to see some of the other problems that arise when using too large of a sample size (where the simple solution is to reduce the sample size).

All of these changes increase the difficulty to maintain Quality Control as the sample size increases.

Comment: As a personal example, printing a page at my university cost 2.5 cents per page.  After installing monitoring equipment and a system to charge each student for the pages they printed, the cost to print became 5 cents per page.